# Intersection of non-independent events

Tags: probability

Let $A_1,\dots, A_n$ be not necessarily independent events. What can be said about the relation between $\mathbb{P}(\cap A_i)$ and $\prod_i^n \mathbb{P}(A_i)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very much, in general. Consider a coin tossed just once. Let $A_1$ be the event that it's heads, and $A_2$ be the event that it's tails. Then $\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2) = 0$. On the other hand, if both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are the even that the coin is heads, then $\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2) = \frac{1}{2}$. In both cases, $ \mathbb{P}(A_1) \mathbb{P}(A_2) = \frac{1}{4}$.

In the first case you had
$$\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2) = 0 \lt \mathbb{P}(A_1) \mathbb{P}(A_2) = \frac{1}{4}$$
and in the second you had
$$\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2) = \frac{1}{2} \gt \mathbb{P}(A_1) \mathbb{P}(A_2) = \frac{1}{4}$$